# Create submenus programmatically for existing Menu created from XML

Tags: android, menu

I have created my parent menus in xml , now i don't know how to create submenus under those parents using code. That means , parents are coded in menu.xml and submenus will be loaded based on a dynamic code as and when the data is available.

When i tried to use menu.addSubMenu it is creating a new parent menu item.

Answer (score 11):

mymenu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/menubutton_submenuButton"
            android:showAsAction="always"/>
        <menu>
            <!-- empty submenu, filled programatically -->
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Then later in code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menubutton_submenuButton);
    SubMenu subMenu = menuItem.getSubMenu();
    // @todo: add submenu items programmatically here.

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

okk.. you should try this..

```
private static final int FILE = 0;
    private static final int EDIT = 1;

    private static final int NEW_MENU_ITEM = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int SAVE_MENU_ITEM = NEW_MENU_ITEM + 1;

    private static final int UNDO_MENU_ITEM = SAVE_MENU_ITEM + 1;
    private static final int REDO_MENU_ITEM = UNDO_MENU_ITEM + 1;


@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.i("this is test ", "oncreate option menu is called");
//      menu.add("this is first menu");
//      menu.add("this is second menu");
//      
        SubMenu fileMenu = menu.addSubMenu("File");
        SubMenu editMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Edit");
        fileMenu.add(FILE, NEW_MENU_ITEM, 0, "new");
        fileMenu.add(FILE, SAVE_MENU_ITEM, 1, "save");
        editMenu.add(EDIT, UNDO_MENU_ITEM, 0, "undo");
        editMenu.add(EDIT, REDO_MENU_ITEM, 1, "redo");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Well, here you are creating everything in a code , but i want to use existing menu items those are specified in xml and under that i want to create submenu.

Comment: Apparently, the author of this answer didn't read the question and gave an answer that is not even solving original problem

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very very old thread but hopefully this will help others like me who had the same requirement.

`menu/movies.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_filter"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Filter">
            <menu>
                <group android:menuCategory="container">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/action_genre"
                        android:title="Genre">
                        <menu>
                            <group android:checkableBehavior="single" />
                        </menu>
                    </item>
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

then programmatically on your `activity/fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.movies, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).getSubMenu().findItem(R.id.action_genre).getSubMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Action");
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).getSubMenu().findItem(R.id.action_genre).getSubMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, "Comedy");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to add click Listener on submenu (Action and Comedy).

Comment: @GunduBandagar In onOptionsItemSelected. Get the id of the menu pressed ie. menuItem.getId. Then using if then else statement, check if this id is equal to the action or comedy menu and do the process accordingly.