# invalidateOptionsMenu is not recreating menu on Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to customise the menu entries for my Glass app by using the answer provided here [How do you customise Glass contextual voice menu in an immersion *after* its initial setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762428/how-do-you-customise-glass-contextual-voice-menu-in-an-immersion-after-its-ini) but the menu never gets recreated.

The app is my final university project for home automation. When the user turns on the light I would like the "turn on light" option to hide and the "turn off light" to become visible.

Here is some of my code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
        mPreparePanelCalled = true;
    if (isMyMenu(featureId)) {
        shouldFinishOnMenuClose = true;

        MenuItem menuLightOn = menu.findItem(R.id.action_turn_on_light);
        MenuItem menuLightOff = menu.findItem(R.id.action_turn_off_light);
        if (menuLight) {
            menuLightOn.setVisible(false);
            menuLightOff.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            menuLightOn.setVisible(true);
            menuLightOff.setVisible(false);
        }
        return !mIsFinishing;
    }
    return super.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    if (isMyMenu(featureId)) {
        shouldFinishOnMenuClose = true;
        // Handle item selection.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_unlock_door:
                try {
                    handleUnlockDoor();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_lock_door:
                try {
                    handleLockDoor();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_turn_on_light:
                try {
                    handleTurnOnLight();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_turn_off_light:
                try {
                    handleTurnOffLight();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_set_thermostat:
                handleSetThermostat();
                break;
            case R.id.action_turn_on_kettle:
                try {
                    handleTurnOnKettle();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_turn_off_kettle:
                try {
                    handleTurnOffKettle();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_stop:
                handleStop();
                break;
        }
    }

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    getWindow().invalidatePanelMenu(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

And then when the corresponding function is called, the boolean value is changed:

```
private void handleTurnOnLight() throws IOException {
    String retrievedData = null;
    try {
        retrievedData = new RetrieveData().execute(ServerUrl.serverUrl + "/lighton").get();
        menuLight = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, retrievedData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    LiveCardService.refreshLiveCard(this);

}

private void handleTurnOffLight() throws IOException {
    String retrievedData = null;
    try {
        retrievedData = new RetrieveData().execute(ServerUrl.serverUrl + "/lightoff").get();
        menuLight = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, retrievedData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    LiveCardService.refreshLiveCard(this);
}
```

I'm a real newbie to Glass development, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the changes need to be done on the options menu (and not a submenu), you will need to make the changes in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. I think calling it the way you do would work, but only if you call `invalidatePanelMenu` before `invalidateOptionsMenu`. However, do take note that it makes more sense to move your code to `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply, I tried both of your suggestions, but unfortunately they did not work for me.
If you would like to look at all of my code, it is available at https://github.com/sephallen/HomeAutomationForGlass

Answer (score 0):

for the contextual menu to update you need to invalidate that too.
This can be done by using the following

```
getWindow().invalidatePanelMenu(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am calling this already in onMenuItemSelected override, but its not working for me. Perhaps this is the wrong place to call it?

Comment: I tried using the `setVisible(true)` on my own project and it doesn't seem to work for me either. What I'm doing in my own `onPreparePanel` is inflating a new menu depending on a certain state. You could try using this. But it would seem to a lot of work compared to what you are trying to do here.

Comment: This is something I have considered, but wouldn't I have to create every possible version of combination of things being on and off as a separate menu?

Comment: yes you would. I feel like that shouldn't be the most effective way to do it for you